# I want to do a basic angular 2 unit test for a http get request

Tags: unit-testing, angular

**My tech:** angular version 4, webpack, karma, unit tests in jasmine and typescript.

I want a basic example of how I test my service function that has a http call.

**This is my basic service:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()

export class TestService {
    headers: Headers;
    http: Http;

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
        this.headers = new Headers();
    }

    test = (): Promise<boolean> => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const url = 'http://www.ipsumlorem.com/json';

            this.http.request(url).subscribe(response => {
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    }
};
```

**This is my current spec (unit test) for it:**

```
import { TestService } from './test.service';

import {Injectable, ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {async, fakeAsync, tick, inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BaseRequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, ResponseOptions, Response, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';

let service;

describe('Service : testService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
          TestService,
          MockBackend,
          BaseRequestOptions,
          {
            provide: Http,
            deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
            useFactory: (mb:MockBackend, opts:BaseRequestOptions) => {
              return new Http(mb, opts);
            }
          }
      ],
      imports: [HttpModule]
      }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(inject([Http], (http: Http) => {
     service = new TestService(http);
  }));

  it('should call test function and return a promise with value true', async(() => {
      //Mock response
      TestBed.get(MockBackend).connections.subscribe(c => {
        c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: Promise.resolve(true)})));
      });

      let result = true;
      service.test().then((response: any) => result);
      expect(result).toEqual(true);
  }));

});
```

Comment: Have you already referred to the documentation for [MockBackend](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/testing/index/MockBackend-class.html)? There is a very good detailed example listed there.

Comment: That URL seems broken @Igor - https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Working example:**

```
import { TestService } from './test.service';

import {Injectable, ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {async, fakeAsync, tick, inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {BaseRequestOptions, ConnectionBackend, Http, ResponseOptions, Response, HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {MockBackend, MockConnection} from '@angular/http/testing';

let service;

describe('Service : testService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
          TestService,
          MockBackend,
          BaseRequestOptions,
          {
            provide: Http,
            deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
            useFactory: (mb:MockBackend, opts:BaseRequestOptions) => {
              return new Http(mb, opts);
            }
          }
      ],
      imports: [HttpModule]
      }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(inject([Http], (http: Http) => {
     service = new TestService(http);
  }));

  it('should call test function and return a promise with value true', async(() => {
      //Mock http call
      TestBed.get(MockBackend).connections.subscribe(c => {
        c.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: Promise.resolve(true)})));
      });

      service.test().then((response: any) => {
        expect(response).toEqual(true);
      }); 
  }));    
});
```

Comment: Can you add the imports?

Comment: Need more specifics about "not working". Also, the return type of `test` should be `Observable`, not `Promise`.

Comment: I just want to mock the http and check my function called test returns a promise with the value true. I've updated my unit test to my current attempt. Error I currently get is:  No provider for Http!

Comment: Edited my answer.